# Option[Long] constructor throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, scala, null

There's a Java function supposed to return a `Long` but which might also return `null`. How should that be converted to `Option[Long]` in Scala 2.11? I thought this would be trivial:

`Option[Long]( f )`

However, Scala does not allow `AnyVal`s to have `null` as a value, and that causes this constructor to spit a `NullPointerException`. Not nice.

I feel Scala should just do the right thing, or allow a second constructor that can be used when the value can be an `AnyVal`.

---

Update:

Here's how to reproduce the problem:

```
scala> null.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long]
res2: Long = null

scala> Option(res2)
res3: Option[Long] = None     # this is actually an 'Option[java.lang.Long]'

scala> Option[Long](res2)
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at scala.Predef$.Long2long(Predef.scala:358)
  ... 33 elided

scala> Option(res2).map(_.longValue)
res12: Option[Long] = None    # 'Option[scala.Long]'
```

All of this could imho be fixed within the `Option.scala` [sources](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Option.scala), with something like:

```
object Option { 
    ...
    def apply(x: java.lang.Long): Option[Long] = if (x == null) None else Some(x.longValue)
```

And the same for all Java types corresponding `AnyVal` in Scala: `java.lang.Double`, `java.lang.Float`, `java.lang.Int`, `java.lang.Character`, `java.lang.Short`, `java.lang.Byte` and `java.lang.Boolean`.

Comment: So you have a java.lang.Long, which can be null, and turn it into an Option[Long] which is None if the Long is null?

    Option(x).map(_.longValue) or something?

Comment: It sounds like you may have some confusion between `scala.Long` (unboxed, equivalent of Java's `long`) and `java.lang.Long` (boxed).

Comment: Yep, @RüdigerKlaehn you nailed it. By the time I was writing this I didn't realize they were two kinds of Longs. IntelliJ keeps that pretty well hidden from us.

Comment: Have created SI-9634 https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9634 to fix this in the Scala sources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you have a [java.lang.Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), which can be null, and turn it into an Option[[scala.Long](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Long)] which is None if the java.lang.Long is null?

```
Option(javaMethod).map(_.longValue)
```

Comment: +1. Loosely related, I was bitten by my wrong assumption that `scala.util.Try { possiblyNullResult }` would return a `scala.util.Faiure`. But it will **succeed**. example: `Try { if (true) null else java.lang.Integer.valueOf(55) } ` === `Success( null )`

Answer (score 2):

Try just `Option(f)`. This will return `Option[Long]` in case of `Long` and `Option[Null]` in case of a null. But you can safely cast `Option[Null]` to `Option[Long]`. So something like this might do it:

```
def process(): Option[Long] = Option(javaCall()).asInstanceOf[Option[Long]]
```

**P.S.** I wasn't able to get rid of `asInstanceOf` If anybody has any ideas, please post a comment or a separate answer.

Comment: The type returned by 'Option(f)' is actually 'Option[java.lang.Long]'. I think we'll go along your route, but with '.map(_.toLong)' instead of the asInstanceOf. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, I've missed that completely. Using `.map` is really much better. First part of my explanation is wrong